# Backward Analysis of Expression

Tags: c, algorithm, static-analysis

Suppose I have following code segment in C.

```
i = j = k = 1;

j = (i++) + (++k);

result = i + j + k; //POI
//Expected result = 7
```

Here, I want to find value of `result` through backward analysis. When I perform backward analysis, I will go through following expressions in order.

```
j = (i++) + (++k);
++k;
i++;
i = j = k = 1;
j = k = 1;
k = 1;
```

During backward analysis I will replace each variable by corresponding expression, whenever it is applicable. But I'm confused how to deal with increment/decrement operations.

My current strategy will produce following result

```
result = i + j + k

//after j = i++ + ++k
result = (i+(i+(k+1)))+k

//after ++k
result = (i+(i+((k+1)+1)))+(k+1)

//after i++
result = ((i+1)+((i+1)+((k+1)+1)))+(k+1)

//after i = j = k = 1
result = ((1+1)+((1+1)+((k+1)+1)))+(k+1)

//after k = 1
result = (((1+1)+((1+1)+((1+1)+1)))+(1+1))

//Simplifying
result = 9
```

which is ofcourse not true.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think you made a mistake here

`//after j = i++ + ++k
result = (i+(i+(k+1)))+k`          It is not `k+1` until you go for the `k++` instruction, you also made a mistake after i++

Comment: @Othman; That is the approach currently I'm following. `j = (i++) + (++k)` says `j = i + k + 1`. So, I'm just replacing `j` with it. But I don't know what approach I should follow actually.

Comment: i see what you mean, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be more like this

```
result = i + j + k

//after j = X + Y      // You didn't analyse ++k and i++ yet 
result = i+(X+Y)+k    

//after Y = ++k
result = (i+(X+(k+1))+(k+1)

//after X = i++
result = ((i+1)+(i+(k+1))+(k+1)

//after i = j = k = 1
result = ((1+1)+(1+(k+1))+(k+1)

//after k = 1
result = ((1+1)+(1+(1+1))+(1+1)

//Simplifying
result = 7
```

Comment: Sounds good.
But Now I have to about it's implementation. Anyway, thanks.
I have +1'd.

Comment: You must analyze j = `i++ + ++k` as a normal addition of two values that you don't know yet

Answer (score 0):

The thing to notice here is i++ increases after evaluating, not before.

```
i=j=k=1
++k  //happens before expression
//k=2,i=j=1
j = k + i 
//k=2,i=1,j=3
i++ //happens after expression
//k=2,i=2,j=3
result = i+ j + k
//result = 7
```

Your mistake was increasing `i` before ealuation of `j`, and then getting j=4, instead of j=3

If you want to analyze it backward, something along the lines of

```
result = i + j + k
i = i+1 = 1 + 1
//result = (1+1) + j + k
j = i + k 
k = k+1 = 1+1
//j = 1 + (1+1) 
//result = (1+1) + (1+(1+1)) + (1+1)
```

Comment: Yes. Correct answer is 7 only. My question is how to reach in that answer through backward analysis.

Comment: In backward analysis, we should follow reverse order of execution through systematic approach.
`j = (i++) + (k++)` will be considered at first, then `(k++)`, then `(++i)` so on.

So what should be my strategy when I find each of these expressions?

Comment: @technorevolutionary This is what I offered in the edit (bottom part of the answer), everywhere there is a //it's a comment not a new evaluation.

Comment: Can you please show flow for these expressions as I did in my qustion?
`j = i++ + ++k;
++k;
i++;
i = j = k = 1;
j = k = 1;
k = 1; `

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first decompose the statements into elementary ones as a compiler would do. For instance, using Frama-C to decompose the statements would give something like:

```
k = 1;
j = k;
i = j;
tmp = i;
i ++;
k ++;
j = tmp + k;
result = (i + j) + k;
```

It is then a lot easier to do the analysis.
Consider the sequence stating from the bottom :

```
  // 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
k = 1;
  // k + 1 + k + k + 1 + k + 1
j = k;
  // j + 1 + j + k + 1 + k + 1
i = j;
  // i + 1 + i + k + 1 + k + 1
tmp = i;
  // i + 1 + tmp + k + 1 + k + 1
i ++;
  // i + tmp + k + 1 + k + 1
k ++;
  // i + tmp + k + k
j = tmp + k;
  // i + j + k
result = (i + j) + k;
  // result ?
```

Which gives you 7 as expected.